# Customize the datetime format in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, time-format

When I use the form helper to make a time input,usaually I write code as follows

```
<?php
$options = array(
    'label' => '',
    'type' => 'datetime',
    'timeFormat'=>'24',
    'separator'=>'-'
);
echo $form->input('Service.endtime',$options);
?>
```

But now I get a problem that I want to make a time input style such as

```
month-day-hour
```

Then how can do this with setting some parameters in the helper?Suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `dateformat` option will allow you to configure the date parts.

> Used to specify the format of the select inputs for a date-related set of inputs. Valid values include ‘DMY’, ‘MDY’, ‘YMD’, and ‘NONE’.
>   http://book.cakephp.org/view/203/options-dateFormat

However for this I think that you will need to extend the helper and create a custom function which will return this mixed date and time style. Otherwise I can only think of having two selects, one with month and day, and one for hour. Then merging the data somewhere else, perhaps in beforeSave() or beforeValidate()

Comment: after going through the form.php in the cake's lib,I got a solution using the single part input function in the helper such as `$form->month()`.Though more parameters to post but still better than do that manually:)

Answer (score 2):

Hope my solution may help someone with the same requirement:

```
<?php
//echo $form->year('Modelname.year',2001,2021,intval(date('Y')),false)."-";
echo $form->month('Modelname.month',date('m'),'',false)."-";
echo $form->day('Modelname.day',date('d'))."-";
echo $form->hour('Modelname.hour',1,date('H'));
?>
```